# laravel 5.* - package driven development - best practices

Tags: php, laravel-5, scalability

this is not a code question about laravel 5.*, it's more like to know if you guys develop your applications using packages ("package driven development" ? Not sure if this is the right definition).

What I mean is: Instead of building an application and create controllers in app/Http/Controllers/, you wrap everything in a package and then 'require' that package using composer (like a wordpress plugin).

I'm trying to think in a way to isolate the core Laravel from my specific application and save time later when it's time to upgrade when a new Laravel version is available.

In my case I'm having some issues moving from version 5.2 to 5.3 because I have some customization in the registration and login process - It might be because I'm not using the right approach to write the code (patterns), so I'd like to hear from more experienced Laravel developers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great thing about Laravel, there's almost always a package for what you want to do. You can either create your packages as packages on composer, or you can install a module package and create them as modules.

For my projects I tend to use [caffeinated/modules](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules). I've tried a few and IMO it's the easiest to use.